# Embedded system engineer's guide to GUI

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, communication, control, books

For an engineer who solely knows C/C++ for programming microcontrollers, and has no idea about developing fancy GUI application for communication with his embedded systems, Which book and IDE might be a good start for embedded systems engineer for developing GUIs in Windows?

Comment: This is going to be closed soon. However be more specific on what you seek. Are you seeking to write your own windowing systems , then you should read a book like this : http://books.google.com/books/about/Computer_Graphics_C_Version_2_E.html?id=dvrTIelDhJUC

Comment: The reason for asking such question on electronic.stackexchange rather than overflow is that embedded systems engineers who are already working in GUI development for their own embedded system are much likely to point to the right book than pure programmers. I just want to develop an application on windows that has a good looking GUI to controlling functions on embedded system, like open/close a relay, communicate via USB/serial port. Let it be clear. Of course I do not want to master GUI but need bare minimum to develop a GUI and focus mainly on operation in the embedded system. Thank you

Comment: @sandundhammika Please note the question clearly mentions that a need for developing a simple GUI for controlling an embedded system by an embedded system engineer. Thank you

Comment: Oky,But This is not the place to ask questions on windows programming.Normally when I doing windows GUI programming I just directly use win32 API or library like QT/wxWidget. Most of times I use win32 API. The book that I'm using is " Petzold._Programming_Windows_(5th)" book. QT/wxWidget is a easy option. You could use USBExpress , libusb like API for communications over usb. Serial communication is easily done with win32 API.

Comment: I noticed you just updated to include for Windows. In my opinion for Microsoft platforms C / C++ is pretty much dead for GUI development, maybe C# is a good choice. But it probably is a better question for SO even given the slight embedded aspect (and I don't often say that).

Comment: @peterJ ok, so can we move this question to SO then.

Comment: @Osaid, I can't personally but wait to see what happens, it might be recommended for migration. Or maybe others will see it differently and give you a good answer but give it a while and see what happens.

Comment: @Osaid first you have to choose the platform and the library of your choice. I told him C/C++ because he mentioned that he only know C/C++ so he could easily understand the source code examples which are written with C/C++. Ya even Matlab have a GUI scripting language which allows USB/Serial communication and also a WYSWYG GUI maker.

Comment: @PeteJ me too PeteJ , sometimes SE like this are so discouraging to new people.

Answer (score 1):

The very simplest way to generate a GUI application with a range of simple dialogs is to use a small tool called Zenity (another version is called Gdialog).

It is actually a small program which you can run from the command line, or shell script or batch file. Or however you invoke an external command from your C program. When it exits, it gives a return code and a string on stdout : this string is the output of that dialog : filename to open, the list item selected, the edited text file, whatever.

It won't do complex things such as graphics but for simple GUI apps it works really well and it's much simpler to develop an app : test each dialog directly from the command line until it does what you want.

I've only used it on Linux but it's such a handy little tool, it would surprise me if there wasn't a Windows port available.

Comment: in linux this is very easily built with 'kmdr-executor' which is my swiss army kinfe.